# Random Bytes added to an end of a buffer

Tags: c++, stream, unmanaged

I was making a re-creation of some System.IO functions from that class.
When I setup a buffer and allocate n number of bytes it'll read bytes to that and then add random bytes to the end of that buffer.

For example:

My Main:

```
int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    SetConsoleTitle(TEXT("Stream Test."));
    cout<<"Press any Key to begin reading.";
    cin.get();
    const char* data = File::ReadAllBytes(args[1]);
    Stream* stream = new Stream(data);
    char* magic = new char[8];
    stream->Read(magic, 0, 8);
    magic[8] = '\0';
    cout<<magic<<endl<<endl;
    delete[]data;
    cout<<"Press any key to quit.";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

and here is my System::IO namespace + stream class:

```
namespace System
{
    namespace IO
    {
        class File
        {
        public:
            static char* ReadAllBytes(const char *name)
            {
                ifstream fl(name, ifstream::in|ifstream::binary);
                fl.seekg( 0, ifstream::end );
                size_t len = fl.tellg();
                char* ret = new char[len+1];
                ret[len] = '\0';
                fl.seekg(0); 
                fl.read(ret, len);
                fl.close();
                return ret;
            }

            //not sure of this use yet.
            static size_t fileSize(const char* filename)
            {
                ifstream in(filename, ifstream::in | ifstream::binary);
                in.seekg(0, ifstream::end);
                return in.tellg(); 
            }
        };

        class Stream
        {
        public:
            const char *_buffer;
            __int64 _origin;
            __int64 _position;
            __int64 _length;
            __int64 _capacity;

            bool _expandable;
            bool _writable;
            bool _exposable;
            bool _isOpen;

            static const int MemStreamMaxLength = 2147483647;

            Stream()
            {
                InitializeInstanceFields();
            }

            Stream(const char *buffer)
            {
                _buffer = buffer;
                _length = strlen(_buffer);
                _capacity = _length;
                _position = 0;
                _origin = 0;
                _expandable = false;
                _writable = true;
                _exposable = true;
                _isOpen = true;
            }

            int ReadByte()
            {
                if (_position >= _length)
                    return -1;
                return _buffer[_position++];
            }

            void Read(char* &buffer, int offset, int length)
            {
                if((_position + offset + length) <= _length)
                {
                    memcpy( buffer, _buffer + (_position + offset), length );
                    _position += length;
                }
            }

            private:
                void InitializeInstanceFields()
                {
                    _origin = 0;
                    _position = 0;
                    _length = 0;
                    _capacity = 0;
                    _expandable = false;
                    _writable = false;
                    _exposable = false;
                    _isOpen = false;
                }
        };
    }
}
```

This is what ends up happening:
[image: What happens]

Can anyone explain why this happens, how I can fix, or anything else? I'm new to C++ so any explanations would help. Also please don't criticize my scripting, I know it may be bad, outdated, deprecated, etc. but I'm open to learning and any helping advice goes for the better. :)

Comment: Missing null terminator? `magic[7] = '\0';`.

Comment: @JesseGood wow I was doing = '/0'!! Thanks so much, but can you explain why I have to do that in the first place? I read somewhere that windows doesn't always allocate the n amount of space you tell it to or something around those lines.

Comment: Still it would have the first 8 bytes in the file and then junk without null termination right?

Comment: @user1425433: In C++, the null terminator signifies the end of your string. Without it, there is no way of knowing when your string ends. In C++, keeping track of the size of your array, etc. has to be done by the programmer, when you do `cout << magic`, characters will be print until a null terminator is reached. Although your array is only 8 `char`s, often times you can access memory past the end of your array (although this is technically UB) unless you hit a page boundary. Unlike other languages, accessing memory past the end of the array is possible, these are the random bytes you see.

Comment: @JesseGood Thanks for explaining it! That really helped. That's why it's C Strings. :p I guess I'll have to make my own type to do arrays well. Since pointers only point to an address in memory and have no definite length.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `operator << (char *)` on C-style strings, not arbitrary arrays of characters. How would you expect it to know how many characters to output?

Comment: @DavidSchwarts it is a comment

Comment: I understand, I would only output C Strings in console anyway.. but wouldn't it know from: char* data = new char[8]; aren't you telling it that it will be an array of chars 8 bytes long? also should I use unsigned char or does it matter?

Comment: @user1425433 No. Do yourself a favour and read a *book* about C++ rather than assuming you can reuse your C# knowledge because it starts with 'C', too. The only thing that C# arrays have in common with C++ arrays are the square brackets.

Comment: @user1425433: All you're passing to `operator <<` is a `char *` -- a pointer to some address in memory. How can you tell from a pointer to a single character how many characters you should print? You do pass that `8` to `operator new`, but that just gives you back a `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the file was not opened correctly and thus the magic buffer is not set at all which leaves it with initialized junk data:

> If the constructor is not successful in opening the file, the object
>   is still created although no file is associated to the stream buffer
>   and the stream's failbit is set (which can be checked with inherited
>   member fail).
>   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/

Try adding more error checking along the way (using cout), especially when opening and reading the buffer. Perhaps set the magic buffer to zero or something recognizable that is overwritten when successful.